# When will Ubuntu One be available in German and other languages?

Tags: ubuntu-one, language-support

Ubuntu One is a very good service. But at the moment nearly everything is in only available in english and not in other languages like german, french etc.. Also the terms of use are only english. Lots of people do not use Ubuntu One because they cannot understand the terms of use completely.

Comment: Now that is a good question its possible you might need to open a launchpad bug about the lack of translation. Its possible there may be some gray area as U1 is propitiatory but I can't see it as a problem for them to translate the site.

Comment: Are you referring to the Ubuntu One Preferences on your desktop or the website one.ubuntu.com?

Answer (score 2):

There are no plans to internationalise the website at the moment. Because the website contains a lot of commercial information, we can't have it translated by the community like the client.
Getting professional translations for dozens of languages is a huge undertaking (both in cost and effort).
We do, care about all users, but the translation of the website has not yet become a priority for us.
When it is, I'll make sure we announce it properly.